# Why does this recursive function return None?

Tags: python, recursion

Here is my code:

```
def sliding_window(seq, size, step):
    l = []
    return sliding_window_rec(seq, size, step, l)

def sliding_window_rec(seq, size, step, l):
    if len(seq) < size:
        return l
    else:
        l.append(seq[:size])
        seq = seq[step:]
        sliding_window_rec(seq, size, step, l)
    
print(sliding_window(seq, size, step))
```

This prints None.

If I add *print(l)* inside the function *sliding_window_rec*, it prints a list. So why does it return None and not a list when I do *return l*?

Comment: You call `sliding_window_rec` recursively, but don't return what *it* returns.

Comment: This type of recursion isn't considered good style in Python. Making the function tail-recursive isn't useful, because Python doesn't do tail-call optimization.

Comment: inside `else:` you runs `sliding_window_rec(...)` but it should be with `return` like `return sliding_window_rec(...)`